# Paypal CVV issue in new sdk for android

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am integrating the new sdk of paypal which i downloaded from github. Everything works fine with me. I just encountered a problem if I type a wrong cvv number it accepts it and proceeds to payment and returns Status as completed. Its happening just in case of Cvv number .Please help me I am really in need of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this on the sandbox or live environment?  Sandbox is generally very forgiving.

Comment: Yes, unlike in sandbox, the cvv will be properly validated and authenticated with the credit card processor.